# Why was Brock Samson assigned to protect the Venture family?

Tags: venture-bros

Why did OSI assign their best agent to protect the Venture family in the first place?  What was his actual mission?

Comment: I always thought it was in case Dr. Jonas Venture left something behind worth reporting back on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think he was assigned as the Venture bodyguard as punishment for investigating the Guild of Calamitous intent.  (See the Invisible Hand of Fate episode in Season 3)

Rusty Venture is a failure as an adult and living in his father's shadow; it's considered a punishment to be assigned to him. Sgt. Hatred suffers a similar fate when he replaces Brock.

Brock's other mission (or real mission) is to kill Rusty if he ever tries to activate the mysterious orb as revealed in [Operation: Rusty's Blanket](http://teamventure.org/vbwiki/Operation:_Rusty%27s_Blanket)

Answer (score 2):

His real job was to protect the orb, not the ventures. In fact he was told to kill Rusty if he ever took the orb, but then he found out the orb was broken and decided against it.

Comment: shady is partly right. rusty realized that since his father hid the orb it must be studied and rusty has one of the few smart ideas of not using it and brock was releaved that he didnt have to kill him. phantom limb wound up with it and tried to use it infront of the guild and the venture group at the venture compound but it was broke (no one knew at the time)